# C#: Creating an object using new but not assigning it. Good idea/bad idea?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it is a good idea to create an object using the new operator but not assign the returned object to any variable. Essentially I am just calling the methods in the same line. For eg:

`new Object().ToString();`

Well I know the above line won't do anything but it is just an example. And here is what my real code line looks like (its selenium specific - that is why I gave the above example)

`new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("fUserCountryID"))).SelectByText("United States");`

What it does in plain english: Find an HTML element on the form with ID=fUserCountryID and select the option with value=United States

The compiler allows me to do this and it works fine, but is it a good programming practice?
Please share your expert comments for I am just a beginner. :)

Comment: Thank you all for quick response. You all seem to OK this method but marked the replies by kprobst and @Bryan Crosby as I got bit more information from them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be judicious in your usage of this, but I don't see a problem with your above code.

A couple of things I always like to ask myself --

1. Does it make your code more clear to read?
2. I may not be touching this code anymore in the future -- will other developers be confused by this?

Just be careful with some objects, for example, that may implement `IDisposable`.  It is a best practice to wrap those in a `using { ... }` block so that their resources are cleaned up explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

It's not bad programming practice if that is what you are asking about. If you have no reason to keep around the reference to the newly created object after that line, then it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly is acceptable.

If you really  don't need the object for anything else there is no real need to store it. Save maybe to make debugging a little easier.

But note that there is no real advantage in not storing it either.

Answer (score 2):

This is very common nowadays with the 'fluent interface' type of object model design. If you don't *need* the reference other than to chain call a method or something like that, then there's no need to keep it around. There's nothing wrong with this approach, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the object only 1 time then whatever you are doing is perfectly fine. But if you intend to keep using the object and keep creating the object everytime you use it is a bad practice. But for your example, it is a fine.

Answer (score 0):

if an object doesn't have any use elsewhere in code it is better not to create objects which remain in memory even when they are not required.